# Neo4j: Change legacy index from exact to fulltext

Tags: rest, lucene, neo4j

In my Neo4j (2.1.1 Community Edition) database I have Lucene legacy index in place called `node_auto_index`:

`GET http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/`

```
{
    "node_auto_index": {
        "template": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/node_auto_index/{key}/{value}",
        "provider": "lucene",
        "type": "exact"
    }
}
```

Now I would like to change the type from "exact" to "fulltext". How can I do that using REST? I tried the following approaches but neither of them worked:

### DELETE and recreate

I tried to **delete** it first before recreating as "fulltext", but it is read-only:

`DELETE http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/node_auto_index/node_auto_index`

```
{
    "message": "read only index",
    "exception": "UnsupportedOperationException",
    "fullname": "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException",
    "stacktrace": [
        "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.AbstractAutoIndexerImpl$ReadOnlyIndexToIndexAdapter.readOnlyIndex(AbstractAutoIndexerImpl.java:254)",
        "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.AbstractAutoIndexerImpl$ReadOnlyIndexToIndexAdapter.delete(AbstractAutoIndexerImpl.java:290)",
        "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.DatabaseActions.removeNodeIndex(DatabaseActions.java:437)",
        "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.RestfulGraphDatabase.deleteNodeIndex(RestfulGraphDatabase.java:935)",
        "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)",
        "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)",
        "java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"
    ]
}
```

### POST to replace

```
POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/
{
  "name" : "node_auto_index",
  "config" : {
    "to_lower_case" : "true",
    "type" : "fulltext",
    "provider" : "lucene"
  }
}
```

```
{
    "message": "Supplied index configuration:\n{to_lower_case=true, type=fulltext, provider=lucene}\ndoesn't match stored config in a valid way:\n{provider=lucene, type=exact}\nfor 'node_auto_index'",
    "exception": "IllegalArgumentException",
    "fullname": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException",
    "stacktrace": [
        "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.IndexManagerImpl.assertConfigMatches(IndexManagerImpl.java:168)",
        "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.IndexManagerImpl.findIndexConfig(IndexManagerImpl.java:149)",
        "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.IndexManagerImpl.getOrCreateIndexConfig(IndexManagerImpl.java:209)",
        "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.IndexManagerImpl.getOrCreateNodeIndex(IndexManagerImpl.java:314)",
        "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.IndexManagerImpl.forNodes(IndexManagerImpl.java:302)",
        "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.DatabaseActions.createNodeIndex(DatabaseActions.java:398)",
        "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.RestfulGraphDatabase.jsonCreateNodeIndex(RestfulGraphDatabase.java:830)",
        "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)",
        "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)",
        "java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Neo4j** does not allow deleting the auto indexes `node_auto_index` and `relationship_auto_index`, nor by REST nor by any other API.

However there's a dirty trick to do the job. This trick will delete all auto and other legacy indexes. It does not touch the schema indexes. **Be warned, it's a potentially dangerous operation, so make sure you have a valid backup in place**. Stop the database and then do a

```
rm -rf data/graph.db/index*
```

Restart the database and all auto and legacy indexes are gone.

Comment: It worked, on Windows I deleted both `myinstallpath\mydbname\index` folder and `myinstallpath\mydbname\index.db` file (deleting just one of the above wouldn't suffice) and the auto-index disappeared, so I could create a new full-text auto-index.

Answer (score 7):

for all the future readers of this question.

I faced the similar situation and found a much cleaner approach to fix this. Instead of deleting the node_auto_index, try the following steps.

open the shell / command line for the db:

```
- neo4j-sh (0)$ index --get-config node_auto_index
- ==> {
- ==> "provider": "lucene",
- ==> "type": "exact"
- ==> }
- neo4j-sh (0)$ index --set-config node_auto_index type fulltext
- ==> INDEX CONFIGURATION CHANGED, INDEX DATA MAY BE INVALID
- neo4j-sh (0)$ index --get-config node_auto_index
- ==> {
- ==> "provider": "lucene",
- ==> "type": "fulltext"
- ==> }
- neo4j-sh (0)$
```

Worked perfectly fine for me . Hope this helps someone in need :-)

Comment: Works great! After doing this you need to trigger a re-index. A simple way to do that is execute an update query like this one: `MATCH (n) WHERE has(c.<some-indexed-property>) SET c.<some-indexed-property> = c.<some-indexed-property>`

Comment: If anyone here is willing to give me advice as to why this operation has stopped working for me, I would be very grateful. [My post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147402/how-do-i-properly-manage-a-neo4j-community-3-0-0-lucene-legacy-index-really-we).